# Resize is working fine but document ready function is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

Resize is working but document ready function is not working.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/3j7nc5qn/)

Image on load:

[image: Image on load]

After resize:

[image]

```
$(function() {
  $('.left').highcharts({
    title: {
      text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
      x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
      x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
        'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
      ]
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature (°C)'
      },
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Tokyo',
      data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
      name: 'New York',
      data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
    }, {
      name: 'Berlin',
      data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
    }, {
      name: 'London',
      data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
  });
});

$(window).ready(function() {
  //alert($(window).height());
  $('.left').height(($(window).height() - 100));
});
$(window).trigger('ready');

$(window).resize(function() {
  //alert($(window).height());
  $('.left').height(($(window).height() - 100));
});
$(window).trigger('resize');

$(window).ready(function() {
  //alert($(window).height());
  $('.right').height(($(window).height() - 100));
});
$(window).trigger('ready');

$(window).resize(function() {
  //alert($(window).height());
  $('.right').height(($(window).height() - 100));
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
$(document).ready(function() {
  redraw();
  $(window).on('resize', redraw);
});

function redraw() {
  var full_width = $('#container').width();
  var right_width = 300;
  $('.left').width(full_width - right_width);
}
```

Comment: post some code and requirement

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3j7nc5qn/

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] and possibly look at the formatting help too. It is not clear what you want to happen. Also why so many different event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3j7nc5qn/6/

```
redraw();
$(window).trigger('ready');
$(window).on('resize', redraw);
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

these methods call inside the functions. check the fiddle

Updated Fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/3j7nc5qn/7/

Comment: Its not working fine. I checked it. The functionality is such that on resize it should work properly. The code which i have mentioned in jsfiddle is working on page resize. Left chart is aligned to 70% of screen and the right content should occupy 30% of space eg. 300px,